# Why Windows generate a lot of process for a compiled Perl script?

Tags: windows, perl

I've written this script (called SpeedTest.pl) to log internet speed due to resolve a problem with my ISP.
It work well, but just if I use a Perl interpreter (if I double-click on the script). I want to compile it to generate a stand-alone executable to run in a different PC without Perl installed.

Well, I've try with pp and Perl2Exe both, but when I launch the SpeedTest.exe i see a lot of process called "SpeedTest.exe" in task manager. If I don't block all these process, the PC OS will crash (a pop-up say: "the memory can't be written, blah blah blah).

Any ideas?

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use App::SpeedTest;


my($day, $month_temp, $year_temp)=(localtime)[3,4,5];
my $year = $year_temp+1900;
my $month = $month_temp+1;
my $date = "0"."$day"."-"."0"."$month"."-"."$year";
my $filename = "Speed Test - "."$date".".csv";


if (-e $filename) {
     goto SPEEDTEST; 
     } else {
     goto CREATEFILE;
                  }


CREATEFILE:

open(FILE, '>', $filename);
print FILE "Date".";"."Time".";"."Download [Mbit/s]".";"."Upload [Mbit/s]".";"."\n";
close FILE;
goto SPEEDTEST; 



SPEEDTEST:


my $download = qx(speedtest -Q -C --no-upload);
my $upload = qx(speedtest -Q -C --no-download);

my @download_chars = split("", $download);
my @upload_chars = split("", $upload);
my $time = "$download_chars[12]"."$download_chars[13]"."$download_chars[14]"."$download_chars[15]"."$download_chars[16]";
my $download_speed = "$download_chars[49]"."$download_chars[50]"."$download_chars[51]"."$download_chars[52]"."$download_chars[53]";
my $upload_speed = "$upload_chars[49]"."$upload_chars[50]"."$upload_chars[51]"."$upload_chars[52]"."$upload_chars[53]";
my $output = "$date".";"."$time".";"."$download_speed".";"."$upload_speed".";";

open(FILE, '>>', $filename);
print FILE $output."\n";
close FILE;

sleep 300;

my($day_check, $month_temp_check, $year_temp_check)=(localtime)[3,4,5];
my $year_check = $year_temp_check+1900;
my $month_check = $month_temp_check+1;
my $date_check = "0"."$day_check"."-"."0"."$month_check"."-"."$year_check";
my $filename_check = "Speed Test - "."$date_check".".csv";

if ($filename = $filename_check) {
goto SPEEDTEST; 
} else {
$filename = $filename_check;
goto CREATEFILE;
                                 }
```

Comment: Wow, is that like a real `goto`? I haven't seen those in AGES!

Comment: Not only the `goto`. The `if($filename = $filename_check)` is always true, because it's an assignment. This is effectively an endless loop.

Comment: so the correct way is  if($filename eq $filename_check) ? What's the alternatives to goto?

Comment: `==` is numeric comparison. `eq` is string comparison. `=` is assignment, and is always "true" if tested conditionally.

Comment: Instead of `goto` the convention is conditional code blocks. Either inline, or subroutine.

Comment: Ok thx, I usually use Python, Perl is something new to me. thx

Comment: Do you use `goto` in python then? I thought that wasn't a done thing there either?

Comment: So you have a compiled script called SpeedTest.exe calling a programm called speedtest (`...qx(speedtest -Q...`). My guess is that this will simply spawn another instance of your SpeedTest.exe which then will again spawn another one which (you might guess) spawns another one which ...

Comment: Unbelievable, what a stupid mistake.. thx Steffen

Answer (score 0):

Well, Steffen really answered this by way of a Comment, but here it is as an Answer.  Just compile your Perl into an EXE that does NOT have the same name as the one that the Perl script is calling, for example:

`speedtest.pl` compiled into `myspeedtest.exe`, which calls `speedtest.exe`

Comment: Yeah, right... I'm quite embarassed at the moment (what a noob mistake)